# Format pandas table and save as pic

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Trying to creat formatted data frame and save as pic
And want it in special style, But I don't know how.

```
import pandas as pd
import dataframe_image as dfi
from  matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

d = {'index': ['23.01.2022', '22.01.2022','21.01.2022','20.01.2022','total'], 
     'col1': [1,2,3,4,10],
     'col2': [100,200,300,400,1000],
    'col3': [10,20,30,40,100],
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d).set_index('index')

c = ["red","tomato","coral","lightcoral","yellow", "palegreen","green","darkgreen"]
v = [0,.15,.3,.4,.5,0.6,.9,1.]
l = list(zip(v,c))
cmap=LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('rg',l, N=256)

test = df.style.format({"col1": "{:20,.0f}", 
                          "col2": "{:20,.0f}", 
                          "col3":"{0:.1f}%"})\
                 .hide_index()\
                 .bar(subset=pd.IndexSlice[df.index!='total',["col2",]], color='#FFA07A')\
                 .background_gradient(cmap=cmap,subset=pd.IndexSlice[df.index!='total',['col1','col3',]])\
                 .set_properties(**{'text-align': 'center'})

dfi.export(test,img_path)
```

What I have:

[image]

What I want to have:

[image]

Does anybody know how to do this?:)

Maybe not exactly like this but with distance between columns/rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a CSS style

```
styles = [dict(selector="td", props=[("border", "5px solid #eee")])]
```

Then set the style to generate your dataframe at your defined style

```
df.style.set_table_styles(styles).format(...)
```

Output with this style:

[image: Sample output]

Comment: Thank you it helped) BTW how to centrilize column names? and how to do line breaks if column name is too long?

Comment: update the styles with the following 
styles = [dict(selector="td", props=[("border", "5px solid #eee")]), dict(selector="th", props=[("text-align", "center")])]